# Why Hbase stoprow is exclusive in a scan?

Tags: hbase

Is there a way  (other than rebuilding the hbase jars) to make the hbase scan(startRown, endRow) constructor inclusive on the endRow side?

My rowkey is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
scan.withStopRow(StopRow, true)
```

Which will include de Stop Row

From the documentation :

[Scan documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html)

[Source code](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#line.519)

You could also use

```
scan.includeStopRow = true;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the version: HBase  client 1.2 :)

Comment: crap, this method doesn't exist in HBase 1.2.... And given the documentation there is no useful method for this. I would suggest doing a classic Scan and then use a Get on your stopRow. You can find example ni the documentation : https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hbase/4448/using-the-java-api/15540/querying-hbase-get-put-delete-and-scans#t=201708171348026880912

Comment: I found a note that may answer my question, but I'm not sure about the result: https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setStopRow(byte[])

The doc says : In order to make stopRow inclusive add a trailing 0 byte

Comment: Try it out and tell us ;)

Comment: We had just to append another zero at the end of the last value (the stop row). It worked!

Comment: @SBA Add that as an answer.